# stop flickering of divs using CSS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to show two divs at the same position after time intervals while hover over mouse by using CSS only.

```css
.showme{ 
    opacity:0;
    transition-property:opacity;
    transition-delay:1s;
 }
 .showhim:hover .showme{
    opacity:1;
    transition-property:opacity;
    transition-delay:1s;
 }
 .showhim:hover .ok{
    opacity:0;  
    transition-property:opacity;
    transition-delay:1s;
 }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <title>HI</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
         <div class="showhim">
            HOVER ME
            <div class="showme">hai</div>
            <div class="ok">ok</div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The problem is even hidden div occupes space in the DOM.
But i want to place div overlapping & display one after other when hover.

Used Display property instead of Opacity but it does not go well with transition.

I dont want to use position:absolute to position 2nd div over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `transform: translate(x, y)`

But if you want to make the 2 divs overlap perfectly, you will have to make sure you know the distances in pixels.

However, if the 2 divs have the same height, you can then just do a transform: translateY(-100%) on the second div.

Keep in mind that if an element's position is neither "absolute" nor "fixed", it will reserve space in the screen

Comment: Yes ,what if i dont know the distances in pixel.

Comment: Thats why i used display:none ,to remove the element from screen,so that second div can be placed perfectly.

But in this case, i cant manage the  delay between appearance of 2nd div and they are flashed if i hover quickly.

Any other idea to work on?